# Multiple windows via SDL 1.2?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am just making a "Paint" program. I completely made the canvas. Now I want to make a toolbar but when I use

```
SDL_Surface *toolbar = SDL_SetVideoMode( ... );
```

canvas disappears and toolbar appears. Is there any way to have 2 (or more) windows in SDL?

*note: I am using SDL 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way with SDL 1.2, but with SDL 2, this became possible (`SDL_CreateWindow*()`) . Note that, this is true only for a true window (i.e. detachable toolbar), not a  toolbar embedded into your application.